# can't restore days of week format

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: CSS example]

The attached image displays the days-of-the-week view of a calendar I'm trying to create, after upgrading from v1.4.11 to v1.6.4. The top section (v1.4.11) added color and rounded edges but I can't get the second version to do the same, even after copying and pasting the necessary code to the new file. If someone can tell me which CSS component that should be affected, I can easily apply a background color to the row and radius to the outside edges. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I want to report on a little progress that I've made. Through trial and error, I found that the text can be modified in the ".fc-content .fc-state-default" section (at least that's what it is in my fullcalendar.css file; not sure if it has been added or modified from the original). The strange thing is that adding a color attribute affects only the day titles, but when you put in "font-weight: bold" or a background color, that affects everything in the table.

Anyway, I would still appreciate tips on how to do the background color and radius corners in the second part of the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better:

```
.fc .fc-grid th 
{
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, found the solution:

```
/*left top cell in personal calendar*/
.fc .fc-grid th.fc-leftmost {
background-position: 0 0;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  }

/*right top cell in personal calendar*/
.fc .fc-grid th.fc-sat {
background-position: 100% 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

/*first row (days of week) for personal calendar*/
.fc-content .fc-state-default {
border-style: solid;
border-color: #D2D2D2; /* inner border color */
background: green;
color: #fff;
}
```